# 2 different colors for background html

Tags: html

I'm kind of new in html.. what is the html and css tags for my background to look like this?

[image]

Comment: this fiddel example http://jsfiddle.net/66B7d/ , and please try your self first its easiest languages you can learn

Comment: @all user is new to HTML, answer should be understood by user!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to introduce extra elements, you can do it like this:

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: grey;
}
body:before,
body:after {
    content: "";
    background-color: blue;
    height: 30%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
body:before {
    top: 0;
}
body:after {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

The proof is in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TSZTu/1/

This solution introduces utilizes the `before` and `after` pseudo elements of the body element to generate the blue bars. Normally they are invisible, but the `content` property gives them content and makes them show. They are inline by themselves, but using CSS you can position them as you like.

**Update:**

I used `absolute` in the example above, but that will cause them to scroll along with your body. Also, they will be on top of any body content. You can fix that using `position: fixed` together with `z-index: -1` as shown here:

http://jsfiddle.net/TSZTu/2/

**Alternative solition per request (although, I would pick the one above)**

As Vucko mentioned, you can use a gradient as well. Now, I'm not very good at building gradients, but fortunately, there are fine [gradient generators](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) online. They will give you a big chunk of code to add support for multiple browsers, and it might look something like this:

```
background: #2989d8; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2989d8 0%, #2989d8 30%, #333333 30%, #333333 65%, #2989d8 65%, #2989d8 65%, #2989d8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2989d8), color-stop(30%,#2989d8), color-stop(30%,#333333), color-stop(65%,#333333), color-stop(65%,#2989d8), color-stop(65%,#2989d8), color-stop(100%,#2989d8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2989d8 0%,#2989d8 30%,#333333 30%,#333333 65%,#2989d8 65%,#2989d8 65%,#2989d8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2989d8 0%,#2989d8 30%,#333333 30%,#333333 65%,#2989d8 65%,#2989d8 65%,#2989d8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2989d8 0%,#2989d8 30%,#333333 30%,#333333 65%,#2989d8 65%,#2989d8 65%,#2989d8 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2989d8 0%,#2989d8 30%,#333333 30%,#333333 65%,#2989d8 65%,#2989d8 65%,#2989d8 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2989d8', endColorstr='#2989d8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Actually this is a bit of faking. As you can see, this is a gradient from blue to blue, followed by a gradient from grey to grey, followed by yet another one from blue to blue.

The effect is quite different, because the gradient fills the total area of the body. And despite the fact that one gradient starts exactly where the last one ends, you can still see a bit of a blurry line between blue and grey (in Chrome at least).

Anyway, this is the result: http://jsfiddle.net/TSZTu/3/

Comment: thanks alot, it worked well ;) one more question.. how can I reduce the height of the bottom blue background line? i want it to be smaller than the one in the top

Comment: In my CSS, there are four blocks, the first is for the body itself., the second is for both the `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements, and third and fourth are only for `:before` or `:after` respectively. Currently both `:before` (the first bar) and `:after` (the second), have the same height of `30%`, which is declared in the second block. By moving `height` from block 2, to block 3 and 4, and then changing the values, you can set a different height for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="blue">
</div>
<div class="grey">
</div>
<div class="blue">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.blue{
    background-color:blue;
}
.grey{
   background-color:grey; 
}
div.blue{
    padding:40px;
}
div.grey{
    padding:80px;
}
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/8Zt7w/2/

Answer (score 0):

This question is ... not complete, or missing something... you need to provide more information.

On the HTML tag itself, you would use something like

```
<body bgcolor="#ff0000">
<body bgcolor="red">
```

For CSS you can use something like

```
<body style="background-color:#ff0000;">
<body style="background-color:red;">
```

Simply, i would suggest that you use google and start with some basic tutorials.. StackOverflow is not a tutorial source... Once this question is answered, we do not want the next question to be... How do i insert text... While people are here to help, you should learn a basic understanding of HTML/CSS

Answer (score 0):

```
<HTML>

<style>
Body{
 Background-color:blue;

}

#grey
 Margin: auto;
 Background-color:grey;
 Height:300px;

}
<body>
<div Id='grey'>

</div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Something like this...?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this css work as above image using single div:**

```
div {
    height: 400px;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2853c5 0%, #2853c5 20%, #7e7e7e 20%, #7e7e7e 80%,#2853c5 80%,#2853c5 100%); /* FF3.6+ */


}
```

Comment: If you tried this in any other browser than Firefox?

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
            .blueclass
            {
                background-color:Blue;
                }
            .grayclass
            {
                background-color:Gray;
                }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr class="blueclass">
            <td width="200px" height="200px">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="grayclass">
            <td height="200px">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="blueclass">
            <td height="100px">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```